# Extend jQuery table search script

Tags: jquery, search

I have a jQuery table search script from [jQuery scripts](http://www.jqueryscript.net) and now I want to extend it to show an message in `<p>` tag if no result is found.

The script is the following:

```
$('#searchInput').on('change, input', function() {
    selectOptionFilterVehicle();
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();
    $('#vehicleTable tbody tr').each(function() {
        var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

I thought I can add a simple `$('#noVhicle').html('Nothing found');` and `$('#noVhicle').hide();` in the if statement but fail.

Now I am a little bit confused, would someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle founded items you need to create variable and increase it if something found, otherwise you can show your error

```
$('#searchInput').on('change, input', function() {
    // selectOptionFilterVehicle();
    var founded = 0;
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();

    $('#vehicleTable tbody tr').each(function() {
        var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if (lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            founded += 1;
        }
        if ( founded === 0 ) {
            $("#noVhicle").show();
        } else {
            $("#noVhicle").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83Ljrjcz/2/)